# unity pathfinding algorithm c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I have a class containing three path-finding algorithms: Depthwise, Breadthwise and AStart. I use these methods in an GameObject script, which has to be patrolling in a graph, but when I run it, the object doesn´t move, it stays in the first node.

```
public static List<Node> Depthwise(Node start, Node end) {
    Stack<Node> work = new Stack<Node>();
    List<Node> visited = new List<Node>();

    work.Push(start);
    visited.Add(start);
    start.history = new List<Node>();

    while(work.Count > 0)
    {
        Node current = work.Pop();
        if(current == end)
        {
            List<Node> result = current.history;
            result.Add(current);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < current.neighbors.Length; i++)
            {
                Node currentChild = current.neighbors[i];
                if (!visited.Contains(currentChild))
                {
                    work.Push(currentChild);
                    visited.Add(currentChild);
                    currentChild.history = new List<Node>(current.history);
                    currentChild.history.Add(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static List<Node> Breadthwise(Node start, Node end) {
    Queue<Node> work = new Queue<Node>();
    List<Node> visited = new List<Node>();

    work.Enqueue(start);
    visited.Add(start);
    start.history = new List<Node>();

    while(work.Count > 0)
    {
        Node current = work.Dequeue();

        if(current == end)
        {
            List<Node> result = current.history;
            result.Add(current);
            return result;
            //we found a solution
        }else
        {
            for(int i=0; i < current.neighbors.Length; i++)
            {
                Node currentChild = current.neighbors[i];
                if (!visited.Contains(currentChild))
                {
                    work.Enqueue(currentChild);
                    visited.Add(currentChild);
                    currentChild.history = new List<Node>(current.history);
                    currentChild.history.Add(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ///No available path
    return null;
}

public static List<Node> AStar(Node start, Node end)
{
    List<Node> visited = new List<Node>();
    List<Node> work = new List<Node>();

    start.history = new List<Node>();
    start.g = 0;
    start.h = Vector3.Distance(start.transform.position, end.transform.position);

    visited.Add(start);
    work.Add(start);

    while (work.Count > 0)
    {
        //get the current one
        Node current = work[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < work.Count; i++)
        {
            //check if answer is here
            if (work[i] == end)
            {
                //return path
                List<Node> result = work[i].history;
                result.Add(work[i]);
                return result;
            }

            if (work[i].F < current.F)
            {
                current = work[i];
            }
        }
        work.Remove(current);

        //traverse children
        for(int i=0; i<current.neighbors.Length; i++)
        {
            Node currentChild = current.neighbors[i];
            if (!visited.Contains(currentChild))
            {
                visited.Add(currentChild);
                currentChild.history = new List<Node>(current.history);
                currentChild.history.Add(current);

                //g-certain
                currentChild.g = current.g + Vector3.Distance(current.transform.position, currentChild.transform.position);
                //h-heuristic
                currentChild.h = Vector3.Distance(currentChild.transform.position, end.transform.position);
                work.Add(currentChild);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you actually call any of these functions?